# How to convert "9:00 PM EST" to a Date object

Tags: java, android, date, time, timezone

I am developing an Android application and require some basic datetime manipulation. I have a Date object (from Java.util.Date) holding a specific date. I need to add a specific time to it. The time I have is a string in this format: "9:00 PM EST"

How would I "add" this time to the previous date? If the Date object currently has: "4/24/10 00:00:00"

How would I change it to instead be: "4/24/10 09:00:00 EST"

I would prefer to do this without the use of an external library, if possible.

Comment: You realize libraries exist because dates are complicated as hell (dates are discussed about half way down http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) due to (frequently changing) local laws.

Comment: Does Android have java.util.DateFormat?

Comment: @R0MANARMY: I understand that they're complicated, hence my asking for help.  If it's absolutely impossible to do what I want without the use of a library, then I'll look into libraries.  

@Thilo: Yes, it does have java.util.DateFormat.

Comment: @Bara: It isn't impossible, but if you read Jon Skeet's post on it you'll see why it's complicated and error prone.  If you're doing this for an app that's entirely for personal use then it's not a big deal.  If it's something you plan to market, it gets more complicated.  For example [some date] + 9 hours could be 8AM, 9AM, or 10AM depending on geographic location and year (remember how in the US daylight savings time got pushed up by two weeks?).  This is why it is better to use a library that will (hopefully) be updated to account for such changes.

Comment: @R0MANARMY: Well, if the time is set to 9AM EST, how can it change it something other than 9AM EST?  Are you specifically talking about comparing 2 times in different timezones (which I'll be doing later)?

Comment: @Bara: Every date implementation I know of (granted, not that many) are stored as an offset from a given time point.  In .NET (what I work with) staring point is midnight, January 1st, 0001.  For example, midnight tonight was 634061952000000000.  To get the offset for 9AM today, you have to add **[some number]** to 634061952000000000.  Based on what year, what geographic location, and day of year, **[some number]** will be different.  Sometimes it'll represent 10 hours, sometimes 9, sometimes 8.  This is why date math is complicated and why using a library is better.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll just go ahead and use JODA then.  Thanks for the responses everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Use SimpleDateFormat with format as "K:mm a vvv". The parse function will return you the date object.